# How to determine number of In-app Billing subscribers?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

Programmatically, I understand how to manage a single users subscription, but have not found a way to retrieve a holistic picture of [In-app Subscriptions](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html).

The closet thing I've found in the [In-app Subscription documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#payment) deals with tracking subscriptions to order numbers:

> To help you track transactions relating to a given subscription, Google Wallet provides a base Merchant Order Number for all recurrences of the subscription and denotes each recurring transaction by appending an integer.

Using this mechanism in a roundabout way one can determine current subscription orders, but this doesn't give a clear picture of subscribers. How do you enumerate the number of users who are currently signed up for an In-app Subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Finance overview for an app in the [Google Play Store Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) provides a summary of app revenue. In addition to App Sales the Fiance screen details a summary for Subscriptions which breaks down revenue by: day, last 7 days, last 30 days and overall.